# How to Automate Outlook to Count Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, python, javascript

Gentlemen, I have a graph made in Python where it shows the count of how many emails were received for "Refunds", "Received", "Account Closure". However, this "data" is counted manually by a person, he looks at the email daily, searches the emails that go to the general box that have these keywords, and puts in a spreadsheet how many emails arrived for each of these "Refunds", " Received"...

Proposal: Would it be possible to somehow do something that automatically counts with Outlook Emails and sends the information to this graph? So when these emails are sent, will the graph be automatically updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edited with JSON parsing example)*

It is possible to automatically count emails and update a graph using Outlook and Python. Here are the steps you can follow to achieve this:

Set up the Microsoft Outlook API: Follow the instructions in the Microsoft Outlook API documentation to set up your app and get an API key.

Connect to the Outlook API using Python: Use the requests library in Python to send a request to the Outlook API and retrieve the emails that contain the keywords "Refunds", "Received", and "Account Closure".

Parse the email data: Use the json library in Python to parse the response from the Outlook API and extract the relevant information (e.g. subject, sender, etc.)
Parsing example:

```
import json

# Assume that the response from the Outlook API is stored in a variable called "response"
data = json.loads(response)

# Extract the subject of the email
subject = data['subject']

# Extract the sender of the email
sender = data['sender']['emailAddress']['name']

# Extract the body of the email
body = data['body']['content']

# You can continue to extract other relevant information as needed
```

Count the emails: Use a Python script to count the number of emails for each keyword and store the counts in a dictionary.

Update the graph: Use a library like matplotlib or plotly to update the graph with the new counts. You can do this by updating the data in the existing plot or creating a new plot and displaying it.

Set up a schedule: Use a scheduling tool like cron or Windows Task Scheduler to run the Python script at regular intervals (e.g. every hour). This will ensure that the graph is updated with the latest email counts.

Comment: Interesting, what json library would that be to parse the response from the Outlook API and extract the information?! and another, do you know if there is any place where  teach how to do this more or less?

Comment: To parse the response from the Outlook API and extract the relevant information in Python, you can use the built-in json library. 

All Python libraries are extensively documented. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

YouTube is probably the best place to start

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to implement this. Any questions come i'm back here, very good teaching